# Fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system, and anonymous classes are not static

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, supportmapfragment

I have a supportMapFragment initiated inside a fragment.

This is how I created it.

```
 @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mapFragment = new SupportMapFragment()
    {
        @Override
        public void onActivity(Bundle bundle)
        {
            super.onActivity(bundle);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(HomeFragment.this);
        }

    };
   getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.layout.container, mapFragment).commit();
}
```

My problem is that whenever I create a build, the creation fails saying that "Fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system, and anonymous classes are not static"

I tried setting the variable to static but it still is getting the error.

Please help.

Comment: The _class_ must be static. When you do `new SupportMapFragment() {...}`, that's an anonymous class, which isn't static.

Comment: How should I do it? i mean, there's a reason why I instantiated the fragment inside the class so I cannot use the user findFragmentById method.

Comment: You don't have to include it in your layout in a `<fragment>` element, and `findFragmentById()` it. You just need to create a concrete subclass, and create an instance of that before transacting it.

Answer (score 1):

```
static class MySupportMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment{
    XXX mMapFragment;
    MySupportMapFragment(XXX mapFragment){
        super();
        mMapFragment = mapFragment;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivity(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onActivity(bundle);
        mMapFragment.getMapAsync(HomeFragment.this);
    }

};
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this in app gradle

```
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}
```